# How do I center a background image to its parent element?

Tags: html, css

How do I use the CSS background-position property to center a background image to its parent element? I can only get the background image to center to the entire page.

Comment: Some sample HTML/CSS might be beneficial, in case we're missing the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

works for me. centers horiz and vertically

Comment: this centers relative to the element, not the parent

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that block-level elements which are not re-sized in some way (using height/width or float or margins) will always take up the width of the window, even if the content of the element does not. This means that centering the background to the element will center it to the window as well.

To check if that's the issue, I usually add

```
border: 1px dashed #f00;
```

to the element.

If the element is re-sized, Scott's answer should work.

Comment: You should use the `outline` property for debugging, since it doesn't change the document flow.

Comment: Good idea. I usually just need to see the general geography.