# how to center background image in window resize

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put in my homepage an image using CSS's background-image and position to change its offset.

problem is, when I resized the browser size, the image will stay static and will not move accordingly

how can that be achieved?

thanks

Comment: Can you post some code? is the element to which this background-image belongs relative to the browser size?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I center a background image to its parent element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332469/how-do-i-center-a-background-image-to-its-parent-element)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a percentage: `background-position: 50% 50%` will center the background image.

Comment: Seems ok, but not good enough since I need the center to be fixed. that is - above that background image I have TEXT... I need the image to be located in a specific point behind the text

Answer (score 3):

A few variants to do this:

```
background: url(../images/bodyBG2.gif) center center no-repeat;
```

or

```
background: url(../images/bodyBG2.gif) 50% 50% no-repeat;
```

or

```
background-image: url(../images/bodyBG2.gif);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 50% 50%;
```

If you need to position the background vertically to a certain point (150 pixels from the page top, for example), change the code:

```
background: url(../images/bodyBG2.gif) 50% 150px no-repeat;
```